# jq filter to add multiple conditions to select statement

Tags: jq

I have a json file with contents like:

```json
{
    "name": "pp-site1-r1-n2",
    "state": "Monitored",
    "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
{
    "name": "bb-site2-3par-ilo",
    "state": "Monitored",
    "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
{
    "name": "tm-site1-r3-n4-ilo",
    "state": "ProfileError",
    "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
{
    "name": "tm-site3-r1-n6-ilo",
    "state": "ProfileApplied",
    "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
```

The normal state for servers is ProfileApplied.  So, I want to see all non-normal server states.  So, I run:

```
jq '. | select(.state!="ProfileApplied")'
```

which gives:

```json
{
  "name": "pp-site1-r1-n2",
  "state": "Monitored",
  "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
{
  "name": "bb-site2-3par-ilo",
  "state": "Monitored",
  "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
{
  "name": "tm-site1-r3-n4-ilo",
  "state": "ProfileError",
  "stateReason": "NotApplicable"
}
```

which is good.  However, I'm also not interested in the 3par devices.  If I add to the query with:

```
jq '. | select(.state!="ProfileApplied") | .name | contains("3par")|not'
```

it gives me:

```
true
false
true
```

which is correct, but I really want the json object returned to match the "true" values.  Does anyone know how I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea was right. You need to move the second condition *inside* the select statement to add a boolean AND logic. All `select` needs is a boolean `true/false` to be evaluated, depending on any set of conditions inside. If the conditions evaluate to `true`, the object is selected for output, else it is not.

```
select((.state != "ProfileApplied") and (.name | contains("3par") | not))
```